# Crittercism not working on android service with separate process

Tags: android, crittercism

I have an application which starts android service in separate process. By that mean two processes are running. One is my main application and another is service.

Now I tried to integrate [crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com/) (it's a Mobile Application Performance Management tool) in by below approaches but it is not able to generate crash log for service.

1. Integrate crittercism in app only.

   **Result** : It generates crash log for app only, not for service.
2. Integrate crittercism in service in `onCreate()` method.

   **Result** : It is not showing crash log and also not showing app load in live stats.
3. Integrate crittercism in both app and service.

   **Result** : It generates crash log for app only not for service.

So how do I get crash log for android service?

Here is the code by which I have implemented:

**MainApplication.java**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Crittercism.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "CRITTERCISM_APP_ID");
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Crittercism.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "CRITTERCISM_APP_ID"); // Same app id which is used for MainApplication.java
}
```

**build.gradle** file of both service and main application:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.crittercism:crittercism-android-agent:5.0.6'
}
```

Also added below permission for both service and main application

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: #3 should be the right answer, as you would need to set this stuff up in both processes. You might consider posting your code where you configure Crittercism, and perhaps we can suggest some changes.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have updated my question with code...

Comment: Hey there - one of the founders of Crittercism here, can you send a note to support@crittercism.com?

Comment: @crittercismrob I already have sent a note to support@crittercism.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got reply from Crittercism community and below is their reply:

```
The crashes cannot be captured in a remote service and because its Android issue. We also do not count app loads in remote services but other data is collected: HE, Network, etc. Crittercism counts actual app loads only.

One possible work around is to manually wrap all of the top level methods in the service in a try/catch block. In the catch block, use Crittercism.logHandledException.

Here's an example:

try {
customersTopLevelMethod();
} catch (Throwable t) {
Crittercism.logHandledException(t);

// You probably want to rethrow the exception since the service will now
// be in an invalid state.
throw t;
}
```

Here is the link too - http://community.crittercism.com/questions/1210/crittercism-not-working-on-android-service-with-se.html#answer-1217